# How is Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic non-constant?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing, probability-limit-theorems

I'm reading about [Kolmogorov–Smirnov test](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

> [image]

The Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic is given by $$D_{n}=\sup _{x}\left|F_{n}(x)-F(x)\right|$$

It seems to me that $D_n$ is a constant for each $n$. Could you please elaborate on how $D_n$ is non constant?

Comment: $D_n$ is a random scalar. The empirical distribution $F_n$ has random outcome.

Comment: Empirical distribution function is random so $D_n$ is random as well.

Comment: Hi @Cm7F7Bb, do you meant for each value of $x$, we have $F_n(x): \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable defined by $$F_n(x) (\omega) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{I}_{[-\infty, x]}\left(X_{i}(\omega)\right)$$?

Comment: Why is the downvote? Is there anything low quality in my question?

Comment: @Navier_Stokes Yes. $D_n$ is a random variable such that $D_n:\Omega\to[0,1]$. A different random sample leads to a different value of $D_n$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification @Cm7F7Bb :)

Comment: Paragraph "Kolmogorov distribution" in the reference you give show you that, non only it's not constant but that its (theoretical !) distribution is well known and interesting...

Comment: @JeanMarie, I totally agree with you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cm7F7Bb confirmed my understanding is correct. I post it here to remove my question from unanswered list.

> $F_n(x): \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable defined by $$F_n(x) (\omega) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{I}_{[-\infty, x]}\left(X_{i}(\omega)\right)$$